# Something like LOCK statement in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I need to produce something alike to `lock` statement in C#, a synchronized scope that can include several operations. Suppose I have a table `GeneratedKeys` to track all session keys generated by the database for some other tables. It has a primary key column `[Key]` and a user-defined custom function `dbo.GenerateKey()` that can generate the next random key. I want to insert only unique keys, so I will have to verify the generated key for uniqueness, thus I will have to re-generate it until it gets unique. This requires a synchronized block as several operations taking place here. My approach:

```
WHILE (1 = 1)
 BEGIN
   DECLARE @newKey CHAR(10) = dbo.GenerateKey();
   DECLARE @existingKey CHAR(10) = NULL;

   SELECT TOP 1 @existingKey = [entry].[Key]
   FROM [dbo].[GeneratedKeys] [entry] WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)
   WHERE [entry].[Key] = @newKey

   -- go to re-generate if matched
   IF @existingKey IS NOT NULL 
         CONTINUE;

   -- insert only a unique key 
   INSERT INTO [dbo].[GeneratedKeys]([Key], [CreatedOnUtc])
      OUTPUT [INSERTED].[Key] [Key]
   SELECT @newKey, GETUTCDATE()

   BREAK;
END
```

My question is - did I choose correct combination of locking hints? First, get the `TABLOCKX` exclusive lock for the whole table and extend it until end of remaining block with `HOLDLOCK`.

Comment: Wrap it in a transaction and remove the `holdlock` - an exclusive table lock lasts the duration of the transaction it is within. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58329961/1127428)

Comment: There's no need to bother doing all this, just use [`NEWID()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) which is pretty much guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: You could just put a unique index on the key column, and let the insert fail, then you retry.

Comment: Why not just use identity column? It produces unique number every time.

Comment: I need strings only, not numbers

Answer (score 1):

We are following the below approach to make sure that only one request is executed when there is multiple concurrent requests coming to the database. Basically it is like to simulate the lock scenario in C#.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSequenceNumber]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY

            UPDATE [Rcon.Drawing].[dbo].[TableForLock] WITH (UPDLOCK) set LockValue = LockValue where LockName = 'Dummy'

        -- Logic to generate the next sequence number based on the existing value in the database

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
            PRINT ERROR_NUMBER()
            PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
END
```

I know this may not be the perfect solution, but it works for my case. Please be careful with locks, otherwise you will end up in deadlock situation.