# Multiple incremental series with different prefix in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is the scenario:

**Config Table:**

```
+--------+-----------+-------+
| Prefix | Separator | Seed  |
+--------+-----------+-------+
| A      | #         | 10000 |
+--------+-----------+-------+
```

**Transaction Table:**

```
+----+----------+------+
| Id | SerialNo | Col3 |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 | A#10000  |      |
|  2 | A#10001  |      |
+----+----------+------+
```

The Transaction table has a **SerialNo** column that has a sequential number generated based on configuration table. Configuration table determines the prefix separator and the seed value of the serial number.

In the above example the serial number would start at A#10000 and increment by 1.
But if after few months someone updates the configuration table to have

```
+--------+-----------+-------+
| Prefix | Separator | Seed  |
+--------+-----------+-------+
| B      | #         | 10000 |
+--------+-----------+-------+
```

Then the **Transaction** table is supposed to look something like this:

```
+----+----------+------+
| Id | SerialNo | Col3 |
+----+----------+------+
|  1 | A#13000  |      |
|  2 | B#10001  |      |
+----+----------+------+
```

However there could be no duplicate serial numbers at any given point in time in **Transaction** table.

If someone sets Prefix back to `A` and seed to `10000` then the next serial number should not be `A#10000` because it already exists. It should be `A#13001`

One could simply write a select query with `MAX()` and `CONCAT()` by then it could cause issues with concurrency. Don't want to have duplicate serial numbers. Also, would want to have this as performance friendly as possible.

Another solution that I could come up with is that I create a windows service that will keep on running and watching the table. The records get inserted with null as serial number and the windows service will update the serial number. This way there will be no concurrency issues but then I am not sure how reliable this is. There will be delays.

***There will only be one entry in configuration table at any given point in time.***

Comment: how is `config` updated ? Can you check for existence of `SerialNo` in `Transaction` table before performing any update  ?

Comment: Have a separate table to store the sequence numbers, have a stored procedure which you call up obtain a new sequence number, which you call prior to your next insert into your table in question. You will need an exclusive lock on the table where you store your sequence numbers, and you insert into your main table will have to wait for it to complete. But it won't be long in the scheme of things. And with any non-automatic sequence you have to lock the table which is used to generate it to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Here is a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58329961/1127428) which can be extended.

Comment: @Squirrel config is updated manually. It will have only one row. Changes in config wont be frequent.

Comment: don't allow direct update to the `config` table. Use a stored procedure. With stored procedure, you can check for when`Prefix` existed then get the last `SerialNo` as `Seed`

Comment: @Squirrel no its fine if someone sets configuration values to a serial number that already exists. Suppose user sets it to 12000 but there are already entries such as 12000,12001,12002. So in this case even if the seed has been set to 12000. The next generated serial number should be 12003.

Comment: So using a stored procedure, you will be able to handle that

Comment: Store procedure, and make a lock on the value you read and update them before returning the result so multiple concurrent call will yield different result

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the seed value problem quite easily in SQL Server. When someone updates the seed value back to 10000 you will need to do this via a stored procedure. The stored procedure then determines what the actual next available value should be because clearly 10000 could be the wrong value. The stored procedure then executes `DBCC CHECKIDENT` with the correct "new_reseed_value". Then when new records are inserted the server will handle the values again correctly.

Please look at this link for usage on the `DBCC CHECKIDENT` command. [SQL Server DBCC CHECKIDENT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)